# C++ 11 - condition_variable - wait_until not working as expected

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable

I have implemented a sample program to understand how wait_for and wait_until works in C++11.

Code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

condition_variable cv;
mutex m;
bool flagValue=false;

int sampleFunction(int a)
{
    cout<<"Executing sampleFunction...";
    cout.flush();
    this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(5));
    cout<<"Done."<<endl;
    return a;
}

void sampleFunctionCond(int a)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lg(m);
    cout<<"Executing sampleFunctionCond...";
    cout.flush();
    this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(5));
    cout<<"Done."<<endl;
    cout<<"Value : "<<a<<endl;
    flagValue=true;
    cv.notify_one();
    return;
}

int main()
{
   unique_lock<mutex> ul(m);
   future<int> f1=async(launch::async,sampleFunction,10);
   future_status statusF1=f1.wait_for(seconds(1));
   if(statusF1==future_status::ready)
    cout<<"Future is ready"<<endl;
   else if (statusF1==future_status::timeout)
    cout<<"Timeout occurred"<<endl;
   else if (statusF1==future_status::deferred)
    cout<<"Task is deferred"<<endl;
   cout<<"Value : "<<f1.get()<<endl;

   cv_status statusF2;
   thread t1(sampleFunctionCond,20);
   t1.detach();
   while(!flagValue)
   {
       statusF2=cv.wait_until(ul,system_clock::now()+seconds(2));
       if(statusF2==cv_status::timeout)
       {
       cout<<"Timeout occurred."<<endl;
       break;
       }
       else
       {
       cout<<"Condition variable is ready or spurious wake up occurred."<<endl;
       }
   }
}
```

Output -

```
Executing sampleFunction...Timeout occurred
Done.
Value : 10
Executing sampleFunctionCond...Done.
Value : 20
Timeout occurred.
```

sampleFunction is working as expected as its printing "Timeout occurred" before "Done" but same is not the case with sampleFunctionCond. Though it knows wait_until has timed out but its printing the message after the function sampleFunctionCOnd has finished executing.

Can someone please help me understand this? Thanks.

Comment: Irrelevant to your problem, but actually you could use `cv.wait_for(ul, seconds(2), []{ return flagValue; })` to let the standard library to take care of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a race condition in `statusF2=cv.wait_until(...);` statement. What may happen is that  the wait has timed out and is about to return. To return it needs to reacquire the mutex. At the same time the other thread has acquired the mutex. So, `statusF2=cv.wait_until(...);` can't return till the other thread has set `flagValue` to true and released the mutex.

To fix the code the value of `flagValue` must be checked before checking whether the wait timed out.

Comment: Your last sentence is somewhat obscure.

Comment: Test `flagValue` before testing `if(statusF2==cv_status::timeout)`.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: The `flagValue` is irrelevant. You could remove the 'while' loop and try.

Comment: @KennyTM It may time out while the other thread is holding the mutex. In this case it returns `cv_status::timeout` but **when** it actually returns `flagValue` has been changed.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: The problem is that OP's `wait_until` returns after 5 seconds, instead of the expected 2 seconds. This is irrelevant to the `flagValue`.

Comment: @KennyTM yep, the wait times out but `flagValue` has been set. Depends on your application logic which event should take precedence.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with flagValue as its used to avoid any spurious wake ups. The bug here is, though wait_until should have return after timeout it can not do so as the mutex was held by sampleFunctionCond and it will have to wait for mutex to be unlocked. This is not a bug in above program but in the implementations of wait_until function itself.

Comment: @user1612089 this is essentially what I wrote, just in other words.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin : Yeah i got it. I don't think there is any fix to this problem. Anyways, thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The function "sampleFunctionCond" should not hold the mutex "m" all time. You can try to lock "m" immediately before the line "flagValue=true;".

Comment: It's perfectly fine to notify while holding the mutex and you should always do so unless you have very good reason not to. It's quite easy to run into subtle races otherwise.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Boost documentation says "Note that the same mutex is locked before the shared data is updated, but that the mutex does not have to be locked across the call to notify_one". Also Boost provides example: [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref).
Moreover, consumer ("wait" function) does not return on timeout if mutex is locked by producer.

Comment: 'Does not have to', not 'must not'. See [this page](http://www.domaigne.com/blog/computing/condvars-signal-with-mutex-locked-or-not/) on why you would still want to keep it locked on modern architectures.
The consumer function not returning is also not solved by this, as the blocker here is the sleep, not the notify.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Certanly, blocker is the sleep, not the notify_one. That is why the disput about mutex unlock is irrelevant to the primiry question. I have edited the answer ("lock/unlock" --> just "lock") and hope it is more clearly now. Main idea: try to lock mutex after the sleep and immediately before "flagValue=true".